# Enlarging the click area of a line in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Currently I have a sample application that draws a line and has an onmouseclick listener on the line.

However the line is hard to hit because it is one pixel wide. Currently I make the line wider when you hover over it which makes it easier to aim but it is ugly.

Is there a way to make the "target" area for a mouse click bigger for a line without making the actual line bigger?

Comment: You should define a container like a Region or a VBox for instance. Define your line inside it. Then add a clic listener on your container as an EventFilter. You should catch any clic within the container and so, you can define a bigger hitbox for your line.

Comment: @zenbeni The line is not straight, a VBox or the like would create a disproportiate hitbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another line with same startX, startY, endX, endY properties and make it more thick by setStrokeWidth(10) and not visible by setOpacity(0) on it. After that you can handle mouse events from new thick invisible line as for actual one.

Comment: I was afraid it would have to be something like this... Was hoping there was a better, native, solution. I will wait a bit longer to see if there are other suggestions, otherwise I will sadly accept yours.